# Azure Site Recovery involving Azure Firewall

Tags: azure, firewall, disaster-recovery, azure-site-recovery

I currently have an app running on Azure VMs and the outbound traffic using UDR is funneled through Azure Firewall.

I understand the VMs can be replicated to a secondary region using Azure but not sure how to handle the networking components. With Azure Firewall being a PaaS service, do I have to create an Azure Firewall instance in the secondary region at the time of failover? Same concern with UDRs.

Answer (score -1):

*We can handle/protect the networking components using below following steps*

*I have created the vm with recovery vaults*
*After creating enabled the recovery vaults and I am able to see my recovery site is healthy*

[image]

*Open the replica item in the over view clicked on* ***test failure*** *before beginning the failure I shutdown the machine and the operation will be started and processed successfully*

*To finish the failure click on* ***Commit*** *to complete the failure*

*To reprotect the VM on the keyvault overview click on* ***Re-Protect*** *button*

[image]

*Verify the replication direction and review the target settings for the regions by click on ok to start the reprotect process*

*Use this  [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-failover-failback#reprotect-the-vm) for more information*

*For setting up for [URD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress-outboundtype) Refer this document*

Comment: How anout Azure Firewall which is a PaaS service? Do we have to create a new instance in the target region?

Comment: @Krish no need to create the firewall that which is pass region, and no need to create the new instance it will reprotect the existing region itself.